# Error trying to store image into table

Tags: java, oracle

When I try to insert an image into a table like

```
insert  into IMAGETABLE values('C:\Users\wecme\Desktop\bharath_java_test1.jpg')
```

the following error is raised:

```
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-01465: invalid hex number
01465. 00000 -  "invalid hex number"
```

What should i do?

Comment: What is structure of IMAGETABLE? Are you trying to load an file from an OS directory?

Comment: yes. these are the commnds   create table imageTable(image blob);
insert  into IMAGETABLE values("b.jpg");

Comment: Is this file on a directory on your database server?

Answer (score 1):

The column in your table is defined to contain a BLOB and you are putting in a String value (the location of the file, not the file content itself).

First load the content of the file into a ByteArray and then store it into your database (as a BLOB or CLOB):

You could do something like this:

```
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.Path;

Path path = Paths.get("C:\Users\wecme\Desktop\bharath_java_test1.jpg");
byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
```

This reads the file content into a byte[]. This byte[] can then be written into your database column. (I assuming your column definition is a CLOB/BLOB)

Comment: then how to specify the image path to ioracle

Comment: i want it store from sql developer, if i give path its giving like invalid hexnumber.